# Does this constitute a proof? - Infinite reduction of criteria

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

Lets say I have a conjecture that I need to prove true for all integers. And I find a way to reduce the problem to only numbers of the form:

$N ≡ 1\pmod{2}$

But in doing so also then find a way to reduce the problem to only numbers of the form

$N ≡ 1\pmod{4}$

and again to $N ≡ 1\pmod{8}$

and further to $N ≡ 1\pmod{16}$

then suppose I found an inductive way to show that if I have reduced it to $N ≡ 1\pmod{2^n}$, then I can further reduce the problem to $N ≡ 1\pmod{2^{n+1}}$

Taking this to its limit, I would then have to only prove the problem true for $N ≡ 1\pmod{ ∞}$ - Ignoring the casual use of infinity for lack of better notation.

Would it constitute a proof to show that my problem is true for $N=1$ and therefore all numbers?

I feel like by the nature of this structure being setup that the underlying conjecture must be true.

Comment: Of course. I think the AM-GM  inequality in general is also proved in a very similar manner. In writing, I do not know how to justify what you have done, but it certainly is correct. Can you anyway provide details about the problem you are working  on?

Comment: Sure. It's the Collatz Conjecture.

I think this being validated as true was the final step in my proof being pseudo formal (everything there, just not written up)

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг does your comment still stand now that the notation has been updated?

Comment: No, it does not. I am sorry for my mistake.

Comment: That's correct. If you can prove that $N\equiv 1\mod 2^k$ for all $k$, then for any $N\ne1$ there is a $k$ such that $N\not\equiv1\mod k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the statement $P(N)$ which says "$N=1$, or $N$ is both even and odd". The statement "$P(1)$" is true. The statement "if $P(N)$ is true for all $N \equiv 1$ mod $4$ then $P(N)$ is true for all $N \equiv 1$ mod $2$" is also true, which reduces the mod 2 statement to the mod 4 statement. The statement "if $P(N)$ is true for all $N \equiv 1$ mod 8 then $P(N)$ is true for all $N \equiv 1$ mod $4$" is also true, which reduces the mod 4 statement to the mod 8 statement. And so on, so the mod $2^k$ statement may be reduced to the mod $2^{k+1}$ statement for all $k$. But $P(N)$ is true only for $N=1$.

Comment: With the updated notation, I'm guessing this answer is no longer relevant? It appears to be answering a different question which I guess the original notation leaned towards.

Comment: No, this answer addresses the question as it is currently written. The conjecture that one wishes to prove for all integers is named $P(N)$. The particular $P(N)$ in my answer is not true for all integers. Nonetheless it satisfies all of the conditions of your "infinite reduction" proof scheme, as the answer shows. So your infintie reduction proof scheme does not work.

Comment: I see.

Damn. Cheers for your help @Lee Mosher! I'll re-fudge what I've learned to concoct a different proof. Or rather, an actual proof.

Answer (score 0):

Simply verifying $N=1$ would not be sufficient. You'd need to prove it for some $n$, since you can't induct backwards from $\infty$.

Comment: I can show it true for any N. Does this help?